# How to add extra pricing data in product_data_storage?

Tags: magento2, frontend, cache, recently-viewed, local-storage

I have added extra price in Advance pricing in Admin.
[image]

Everything is working well expect the data for the Recently view products which comes from **Local Storage** > `product_data_storage`

How to add that extra price in **Local Storage** > `product_data_storage` for the *Frontend*?

**NOTE** :

- The frontend product repository is a storage service that uses the
  **local cache** to get product information without making additional requests to the server. The product information it provides is useful
  for optimal mini-cart, widgets, and checkout customizations.

**The product data storage** (`product_data_storage`)

- The frontend product repository uses the product_data_storage section
  of the data storage cache as its data source. This section is
  responsible for holding all product data that come from the server
  when a customer visits a product page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/CustomerData/ProductsRenderInfoSection.php` 
In this file, they are calling `getList` method which processing on product's data, And based on it Magento adding `product_data_storage` and for the price, Magento has used `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Listing/Collector/Price.php` and `vendor/magento/module-tax/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Listing/Collector/Tax.php` but it is not updating price on the front side.

If you want to change full data of product_data_storage you can call your class instead of `Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\ProductsRenderInfoSection` as Magento has called in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/frontend/di.xml` file like below.

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="recently_viewed_product" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\RecentlyViewedProductsSection</item>
            <item name="recently_compared_product" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\RecentlyComparedProductsSection</item>
            <item name="product_data_storage" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\ProductsRenderInfoSection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

I have added some code with an extension attribute to add your custom data in `product_data_storage`. I have added my code below.

Creat `extension_attributes.xml` page in Your module `Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderInterface">
        <attribute code="kunj_data" type="string[]"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now, we need to create `di.xml` in `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml` with code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductRenderCollectorComposite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="productProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="kunj_data" xsi:type="object">\Kunj\Testing\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\Collector\KunjData</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now, need to create `KunjData.php` at `Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Listing/Collector/KunjData.php`

```
<?php

namespace Kunj\Testing\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\Collector;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductRenderCollectorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderExtensionFactory;

class KunjData implements ProductRenderCollectorInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRender\ProductRenderExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productRenderExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderExtensionFactory $productRenderExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRenderExtensionFactory $productRenderExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRenderExtensionFactory = $productRenderExtensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductInterface $product
     * @param ProductRenderInterface $productRender
     */
    public function collect(ProductInterface $product, ProductRenderInterface $productRender)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductRenderExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $productRender->getExtensionAttributes();

        if (!$extensionAttributes) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->productRenderExtensionFactory->create();
        }

        $extensionAttributes->setKunjData([
            'Test Kunj',
            '$1000.00'
        ]);
        $productRender->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }

}
```

Here is my example screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi @kunj thanks a lot for the answer +1, I will check this one and get back to you.

Comment: Sure, happy to help, I will learn new thing

Comment: Hi @kunj I just want to add one more key into into the price data of product_data_storage

Comment: Hi @AdityaShah I have update my code. I have used an extension attribute for extra data.